# Set Pixel Color in Android Rect

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-color

I've created a simple Android view that draws a rect.

```
    private class Rectangle extends View{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    public Rectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0,100, 100);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint );
    }
}
```

How would I go about creating a pattern to fill the rect rather than using a solid color. For example I would like to draw a sinusoidal variation in color along the x direction?

Comment: More precisely, I would like to access every pixel in the Rect to set its color.

Answer (score 0):

Please look on following updated onDraw():

```
    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );

}
```

And turn out this way:

[image]